How to extract a value from a SYS_REFCURSOR?
I have this SYS_REFCURSOS:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <ITEM>
    &lt;SolicitudModificacionContrato&gt;&lt;Id&gt;2201&lt;/Id&gt;&lt;Tipo&gt;&lt;Id&gt;6&lt;/Id&gt;&lt;Nombre&gt;Solicitud de Modificación de Contrato&lt;
    ...
    </ITEM>

  </ROW>
</ROWSET>

How can i get de Id and store in a variable?

Provide correct XML please, and which Id do you want ? the one in SolicitudModificacionContrato or the one in Tipo ? or all ?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; the code you use to generate the SYS_REFCURSOR; an explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, you have XML data (and not a cursor) and the XML is incomplete, invalid and there are multiple Id tags so your expected output is ambiguous.

You don't appear to have a SYS_REFCURSOR, you have XML data and you can parse it using XMLTABLE to get the ROWSET/ROW/ITEM and then, if you have valid encoded XML data (you don't, but if you include the missing tags instead of ...), you can parse that as XML and extract the Id value:
SELECT x.*
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/ROWSET/ROW/ITEM'
         PASSING XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <ITEM>
    &lt;SolicitudModificacionContrato&gt;&lt;Id&gt;2201&lt;/Id&gt;&lt;Tipo&gt;&lt;Id&gt;6&lt;/Id&gt;&lt;Nombre&gt;Solicitud de Modificación de Contrato&lt;/Nombre&gt;&lt;/Tipo&gt;&lt;/SolicitudModificacionContrato&gt;
    </ITEM>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>')
         COLUMNS 
           xml CLOB PATH '.'
       ) xt
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/SolicitudModificacionContrato'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(xt.xml)
         COLUMNS 
           id NUMBER PATH 'Id'
       ) x

Which outputs:



ID




2201



fiddle
